Did the ancient Israelite Kings appoint royal justices?
Did the ancient Israelite Kings appoint royal justices? If so, how is this distinct from the medieval practice of appointing beurim in certain medieval Jewish communities? And what powers were these justices designated with upon appointment? What would the interplay have been between these justices, the ancient rabbinical courts, and the ancient royal court?
